# How to fill a np.nan column in a group based on a value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a subset of a dataframe that I need to backfill using grouping and conditions based on another column.

```
data = [
    ["1A", "aa", "2020-05-09"],
    ["1A", np.nan, "2020-05-09"],
    ["1A", "ab", "2020-05-10"],
    ["2A", "bb", "2020-05-09"],
    ["2A", np.nan, "2020-05-09"],
    ["2A", "bc", "2020-05-10"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["product", "value", "dates"])
df
```

Essentially, for a subset of products I need to backfill the values based on the dates present. For example: For `product` 1A I need to fill in the `value` with `aa` because they both have the date 2020-05-09.

I also need to perform this on a subset of a dataset and have it join back in with the rest of the data once this operation is done.

I tried using a groupby with a lambda function (ffill or bfill) but that doesn't work since I really need to base the value fill off a condition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `transform`

```
df.value.fillna(df.groupby(['dates','product'])['value'].transform('first'),inplace=True)
df
  product value       dates
0      1A    aa  2020-05-09
1      1A    aa  2020-05-09
2      1A    ab  2020-05-10
3      2A    bb  2020-05-09
4      2A    bb  2020-05-09
5      2A    bc  2020-05-10
```

Answer (score 2):

Try via `groupby()` and `ffill()`:

```
df['value']=df.groupby(['dates','product'])['value'].ffill()
```

Output of `df`:

```
    product     value   dates
0   1A          aa      2020-05-09
1   1A          aa      2020-05-09
2   1A          ab      2020-05-10
3   2A          bb      2020-05-09
4   2A          bb      2020-05-09
5   2A          bc      2020-05-10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just drop the na's, then join them with the raw df

```
df = df.set_index(['product','dates']) 
df.join(df.dropna(), how='left', lsuffix="_drop").loc[:,['value']].reset_index() 

  product       dates value                                                                                             
0      1A  2020-05-09    aa                                                                                             
1      1A  2020-05-09    aa                                                                                             
2      1A  2020-05-10    ab                                                                                             
3      2A  2020-05-09    bb                                                                                             
4      2A  2020-05-09    bb                                                                                             
5      2A  2020-05-10    bc
```